# How to get all months with number of months and days from 2 date?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables :

a) clients

```
clients_id    conn_date
=======================
1             2016-06-01     
2             2016-07-17
3             2016-06-22
4             2016-09-03
```

b) clients_pay_bill

```
cpp_id     clients_id    paid_month
===================================
1          1             2016-07-03 
2          2             2016-07-22
3          4             2016-09-09             
4          2             2016-07-22
```

Now I want to show all month**s** with number of days and months of which clients is not paid until current date.

For example :

`clients_id = 1` connection date (conn_date) is **2016-06-01** and he only paid **2016-07-03** month bill till now. So the sql query will be output following months:

```
2016-06
2016-08
2016-09
**2016-07 will not print because he already paid this months bill**
```

and I also want to show number of days and months e.g: 3 months some days..

I can't imagine how the sql query should look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the `conn_date` as well as `paid_month`s  for the client by executing

```
SELECT conn_date FROM clients WHERE client_id = <your_client_id>
```

And

```
SELECT paid_month FROM clients_pay_bill WHERE clients_id = <your_client_id>
```

Then you could use PHP to get an array of all the dates from conn_date to current_date.

Then foreach date check if it exists in paid_month array. If no, then display.

Here is the **pseudo code**

```
$start    = (new DateTime(conn_date));
$end      = date(Y-m-d);
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    if(!in_array($dt,$paidMonthArray)) {
         display($dt(Y-m));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you show me the total working sql query plz?

Comment: I did in my answer. Use PHP to execute the two sql queries. Then get an array of all the months from conn_date to current_date foreach month check if it exists in paid_month array. If no, then display that month

Comment: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  and Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string give and Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in

Comment: That is just a pseudo code. Don't blindly copy and paste it. It's for your understanding. Understand the logic and then make your own code